# How to encrypt a Kibana URL for the dashboard?

Tags: javascript, encryption, elasticsearch, url-encoding, kibana-4

I want to accept some parameters like employee id from a users account and then display the Kibana dashboard which has data associated to that user.
The problem is that the dashboard has a URL like 
`www.kibana.com?empid=101` 
which hits the server directly and then gives back the dashboard. 
I want an application built in Java or PHP which sits in front of the Server that encrypts and sends the URL like
 `www.kibana.com?empid=sdj3829ur23h4r2` 
So if someone changes the empid=102 the web server assumes this as cipher and return an invalid page. 
I have tried a reverse proxy sitting infront of the dashboard server but ,i can only redirect to 1 or 2 dashboards, but i have 1000+ dashboards. So i want to accept the parameters in the application and then encrypt the url and send it back.

Comment: Do your users have to log in in order to see their dashboard? If that's really important to your business that someone doesn't see someone else's dashboard, then you should not rely on parameters (whether encoded, encrypted or merely obfuscated) for applying your security rules.

Comment: They have to login, but that server is different.Without Logging in also you can see the dashboard . The dashboards are accessible from anywhere within  the network and the dashboard is on a different server altogether. So just connecting to the network and messing the dashboard URL will allow anyone to see others data. Is it possible to write a script in Javascript to solve the issue?

Comment: @Val Thanks, How to implement security other than parameters?